# How can I improve Oracle performance when performing a user defined Statistics function?

Tags: oracle, plsql, statistics

An associate of mine converted a javascript inverse chi-square routine to Oracle. The good news is that it returns the same results as the javascript  routine. The bad news is that where it takes 1.5 seconds to return the result in IE or Chrome, it takes 23 seconds in Oracle. Of that 23 seconds >99% is CPU time.

There are two loops in the routines, an outer loop that executes 36 times for the values we are testing with, and an inner loop that runs 10,753 times for the each iteration of the outer loop. It does the same loop in both JS as it does in Oracle. For each iteration of the inner loop it executes an EXP function and an LN function, both of which are intrinsic in both languages.

I have compiled the Oracle code both Interpreted as well as Native, with little if any change (.045 second difference).

I have three questions;

1. Why is Oracle so slow/how can I improve it?
2. Is there an intrinsic inverse chi square function in Oracle.
3. Does anyone have an inverse chi-square function that does not require the iterative looping (or not as much) as the one I am using?

A bonus question is;

Does anyone have a routine that computes Confidence Intervals in PL/SQL, or a language that could easily be converted to PL/SQL?

As requested, here is the code, which is a bit long (The main routine is CRITCHI for testing P=0.975 and DF=21507.38);

```
BIGX Number :=20;

FUNCTION POZ(Z IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  Y NUMBER;
  X NUMBER;
  W NUMBER;
  Z_MAX NUMBER;
  XXX NUMBER;
BEGIN  
      Z_MAX:=6.0;


      IF (Z=0) THEN 
          X:= 0.0;
      ELSE 
          Y := 0.5 * ABS(Z);
          IF (Y >= (Z_MAX * 0.5)) THEN 
              X:= 1.0;
          ELSIF (y < 1.0) THEN
              W:= Y * Y;

              X:= ((((((((0.000124818987 * W
                       - 0.001075204047) * W + 0.005198775019) * W
                       - 0.019198292004) * W + 0.059054035642) * W
                       - 0.151968751364) * W + 0.319152932694) * W
                       - 0.531923007300) * W + 0.797884560593) * Y * 2.0;
            ELSE
              Y:= Y-2.0;
              Y:= (((((((((((((-0.000045255659 * Y
                             + 0.000152529290) * Y - 0.000019538132) * Y
                             - 0.000676904986) * Y + 0.001390604284) * Y
                             - 0.000794620820) * Y - 0.002034254874) * Y
                             + 0.006549791214) * Y - 0.010557625006) * Y
                             + 0.011630447319) * Y - 0.009279453341) * Y
                             + 0.005353579108) * Y - 0.002141268741) * Y
                             + 0.000535310849) * Y + 0.999936657524;
          END IF;
      END IF;



      IF (Z>0.0) THEN 
        XXX:=((X + 1.0) * 0.5);
      ELSE
        XXX:= ((1.0 - x) * 0.5);
      END IF;

      RETURN XXX;

END POZ;


FUNCTION EX(X IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  IF (x < -BIGX) THEN
    RETURN 0;
  ELSE
    RETURN EXP(X);
  END IF;
END EX; 


FUNCTION POCHISQ(X IN NUMBER, DF IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS 
      A NUMBER;
      Y NUMBER;
      S NUMBER;
      E NUMBER;
      C NUMBER;
      Z NUMBER;
      X1 NUMBER;
      EVEN BOOLEAN;                                       /* True if df is an even number */
      LOG_SQRT_PI NUMBER := 0.5723649429247000870717135;  /* log(sqrt(pi)) */
      I_SQRT_PI NUMBER   := 0.5641895835477562869480795;  /* 1 / sqrt(pi) */
  b1 PLS_INTEGER;
  b2 PLS_INTEGER;
  e1 PLS_INTEGER;
  e2 PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN    
 b1 := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME();
 b2 := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_CPU_TIME();
      X1:=X;
      IF (X1 <= 0.0 OR DF < 1) THEN
          RETURN 1.0;
      END IF;

      A:= 0.5 * X1;
      EVEN:= (MOD(DF,2)=0);

      IF (DF > 1) THEN
          Y := ex(-A);
      END IF;

      IF EVEN THEN
        S:=Y;
      ELSE
        S:=(2.0 * poz(-sqrt(X1)));
      END IF;


      IF (DF > 2) THEN
          X1:= 0.5*(DF-1.0);
          IF EVEN THEN
            Z:=1.0;
          ELSE
            Z:=0.5;
          END IF;

          IF (A > BIGX) THEN
              IF EVEN THEN
                E:=0.0;
              ELSE
                E:=LOG_SQRT_PI;
              END IF;
              C:= LN(A);

              /* Timming snippet */
             e1 := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME() - b1;
             e2 := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_CPU_TIME() - b2;
             --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '0-GET_TIME elapsed = ' || e1 || ' hsecs.' );
             --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '0-GET_CPU_TIME elapsed = ' || e2 || ' hsecs.' );
              /* End of Timming snippet */

              WHILE (Z <= X1) 
                LOOP
                  E:= LN(Z) + E;
                  S:=S+EX(C * Z - A - E);
                  Z:=Z+1.0;
              END LOOP;

             e1 := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME() - b1;
             e2 := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_CPU_TIME() - b2;
             --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '1-GET_TIME elapsed = ' || e1 || ' hsecs. Z= ' || Z );
             --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '1-GET_CPU_TIME elapsed = ' || e2 || ' hsecs.' );

              RETURN S;
          ELSE
              IF EVEN THEN
                E:=1.0;
              ELSE
                E:=(I_SQRT_PI / sqrt(A));
              END IF;
              C:= 0.0;
              WHILE (Z <= X1) 
                LOOP
                  E:= E * (A / Z);
                  C:= C + E;
                  Z:=Z+ 1.0;
              END LOOP;

             e1 := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME() - b1;
             e2 := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_CPU_TIME() - b2;
             --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '2-GET_TIME elapsed = ' || e1 || ' hsecs.' );
             --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '2-GET_CPU_TIME elapsed = ' || e2 || ' hsecs.' );


              RETURN C * Y + S;
          END IF;
      ELSE 

       e1 := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME() - b1;
       e2 := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_CPU_TIME() - b2;
       --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '3-GET_TIME elapsed = ' || e1 || ' hsecs.' );
       --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '3-GET_CPU_TIME elapsed = ' || e2 || ' hsecs.' );

          RETURN S;
      END IF;


END POCHISQ;


  /*  CRITCHI  --  Compute critical chi-square value to
                   produce given p.  We just do a bisection
                   search for a value within CHI_EPSILON,
                   relying on the monotonicity of pochisq().  */

FUNCTION CRITCHI(P IN NUMBER, DF IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS 
    CHI_EPSILON NUMBER:= 0.000001;   /* Accuracy of critchi approximation */
    CHI_MAX NUMBER:= 99999.0;        /* Maximum chi-square value */
    minchisq NUMBER:= 0.0;
    maxchisq NUMBER:= CHI_MAX;
    chisqval NUMBER;
    dummy_count number := 0;
    BEGIN
    IF (p <= 0.0) THEN
        RETURN maxchisq;
    ELSE
        IF (p >= 1.0) THEN
            RETURN 0.0;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    chisqval:= df / sqrt(p);    /* fair first value */
    WHILE ((maxchisq - minchisq) > CHI_EPSILON) 
      LOOP
        if (pochisq(chisqval, df) < p) THEN
            maxchisq:= chisqval;
        ELSE
            minchisq:= chisqval;
        END IF;
      chisqval:= (maxchisq + minchisq) * 0.5;
      dummy_count := dummy_count + 1;
    END LOOP;
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('chisqval = ' || chisqval);

    RETURN chisqval;

END CRITCHI;
```

Comment: Showing your code might help. I suspect you might be doing a lot of context switching which won't be helping, but that depends on how you've coded the loops and how you are execting the functions. For the bonus, searching for 'oracle comfidence interval' returned [this](http://numoraclerecipes.blogspot.co.uk/2007/12/sampling-distributions-introduction.html) as the first hit; no idea if it's correct or efficient but it's a starting point maybe.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code which is causing the issue.  360K trips through the inner loop is certainly not helping, but not knowing what's being done 360K times makes it tough to offer any ideas.  Thanks.

Comment: Oracle isn't slow, the implementation is slow.  As Alex noted, show the code will help

Comment: I'm no statistician, but Oracle has a [crosstab](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions170.htm) for chi-squared related data (built in function)  That may help you, worth a look anyway.

Comment: How about a Java stored procedure?

Comment: The chi-squared issue was raised on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ ... the conclusion there was that there was no built-in function for this. Could it be that the Oracle box has slower CPU's to some extent?

Comment: What is `BIGX` set to? And what result do you expect for that input?

Comment: OK, so with my setup I get `21102.404541511389` in about 7 seconds. Just changing all the `number` types to `binary_double` drops that to about 0.2 seconds, but with a slightly different result as you'd expect; `21102.404542145312`. Your `chi_epsilon` value might suggest that isn't accurate enough?

Comment: I made your changes, and it dropped to 2.75 seconds, compiled it native, and it dropped it to 2.073. The good news is this is a slow development box, the production server is faster. It would be great if there were a binary_quad data type, so the resolution would be better.

Comment: I missed one of the variables that needed to be changed to binary_double, and I changed all my functions to deterministic, and it dropped to .2 seconds. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of future seekers, who might not have the patience to trawl through all the comments, the following optimizations were applied to the program to make it run fast.

1. All the numeric variables were declared as BINARY_INTEGER(#).  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#i10726).
2. Functions were declared as [deterministic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/function.htm#sthref1192).
3. Functions were [compiled into native C](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#sthref1072).

(#) On more modern versions of the database PLS_INTEGER is preferred (simply because BINARY_INTEGER is old and deprecated - it gets converted to PLS_INTEGER under the covers) .

---

NB - if the OP or @AlexPoole would care to write a similar response, I'll happily upvote their answer and delete this one.

Comment: I'll still delete it even though it's gained me a Revival badge!